# why isn't this while loop calling its inner functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

I'm trying to write a function that will take 3 urls as command line arguments and log their contents in the correct order.

I use a while loop so I can block execution of http.get before its contents have been logged on the END even of response.

```
var http = require('http')

var url1 = process.argv[2]
var url2 = process.argv[3]
var url3 = process.argv[4]

var urls = [url1, url2, url3]


while (urls.length>0){
    var url = urls[0]
    http.get(url, function callback(response){
    var chars = ""
    response.on('data', function(data){
        chars+=data.toString()
    })
    response.on('end', function(err){
        console.log(chars)
        urls.shift()
    })
    })
}
```

I must be doing something very wrong, because code causes an infinite loop (apparently urls.shift() isn't called).  Can anyone explain the error?

Comment: Move urls.shift() outside of the async code.

Comment: AJAX calls are async. You will have to use callback chain or promise

Comment: Your current code does async calls, but your `while` blocks browser until all requests have ended. It should be infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the while loop is non-blocking because `http.get` is non-blocking. So you have to figure out a way to request these URLs in sequence using callbacks. If you are willing to use `async` module, you can implement it as follows...

```
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');

var url1 = process.argv[2]
var url2 = process.argv[3]
var url3 = process.argv[4]

var urls = [url1, url2, url3]

var results = [];

async.eachOf(urls, function(url, index, callback) {
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var chars = "";
        res.on('data', function(data){
            chars += data.toString();
        })
        res.on('end', function(err){
            results[index] = (chars);
            callback(null, chars);
        })
    })
}, function (err) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

If you don't want to use `async` module, then you'll have to manually keep track of pending URL requests in the while loop as shown below.

Note the use of an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to keep track of current URL in the execution context. This needs to be done because you want the same ordering for results same as the order of URLs provided...

```
var http = require('http');
var url1 = process.argv[2]
var url2 = process.argv[3]
var url3 = process.argv[4]

var urls = [url1, url2, url3]

var total = urls.length;
var results = [];
var processed = 0;

while (urls.length>0){
    (function(url, index) {
        http.get(url, function callback(response){
            var chars = ""
            response.on('data', function(data){
                chars+=data.toString()
            })
            response.on('end', function(err){
                results[index] = chars;
                processed++;

                if(processed === total) {
                    // do something with the result
                    console.log(results);
                }
            })
        })
    })(urls.shift(), total - urls.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Youre just shifting if a response finished. Therefore if the while loop runs, it never shifts and youve got Infinity. May simply shift in the loop itself e.g.:

```
while(urls.length){
  var url=urls.shift();
   ...
}
```